# Corrplot - Como ajustar ao centro no RStudio?

Tags: r

Como faço para exibir o corrplot ajustado ao centro?

Ao executar o comando no RStudio, o gráfico é exibido muito pequeno e posicionado à direita inferior.

```
corrplot(cor.matrix, method="circle")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ajuste o parâmetro `oma` (outer margin area) do seu gráfico. Por exemplo,

```
library(corrplot)
par(oma=c(0, 15, 15, 0))
corrplot(cor(mtcars))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
par(oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
corrplot(cor(mtcars))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado pela resposta. Mesmo aplicando este parâmetro, não está dando certo. Percebi que o problema está no tamanho das minhas variáveis, pois quando diminui o tamanho delas em no máximo 4 caracteres, funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Fechar o RStudio e abrir de novo (ou resetar a sessão do `R`) também é uma opção. Isso reestabelece os parâmetros padrões para o `par()`